# Enabling sort of Notes embedded view in Notes classical Web UI

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I need to modify a Notes legacy web view in the existing application. The view is embedded in a page and accessed by web browser. It looks the column sorting is not available in this case. I confirmed it is available in pure view(not embedded view).
In this case, is there any good solution? I think one of solution is simply to prepare two sorting views and a user chooses from outline or clicking button to change the view. But I'd like to know if there is more good solutions.

Comment: Switch to xpages, or try to use a decent JS (for exampl datatables.net) library to handle the data display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Notes/Domino is this web legacy application running on?  That will help us give you the best answer based on the version  you're running.

Since you're running 9.0.1 you do have a variety of options including XPages.  Since XPages is not an option for you, please explore the other available options from the link below on IBM's site:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EMBEDDING_A_VIEW_OR_NAVIGATOR.html

I think that you'll find embedding the Java view applet a very simple and effective alternative that requires very little development skill.  It also gives the sorting options that you are needing. Here's a link with additional info on this option:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_VIEW_APPLET.html

Comment: Version 9.0.1. I need to modify the legacy view or adding some codes to the legacy design. It's impossible to switch XPages due to the dev period/cost.

Comment: Thanks for suggetion. I'll check it!